# Polling records for status changes using WAITFOR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Under what scenarios would using WAITFOR come in handy.  Wont records be locked while the wait is in progress?  What if you load a group of records you want to process into a table variable or temp table, then loop through the new table, processing one record at a time and using a WAITFOR delay?

Would the above be a good candidate for using WAITFOR?  What other scenarios would it come in handy, and what kinds of things do you want to avoid when using it?

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL Command **WAITFOR DELAY** causes only bathc timing, not data blocking rules.

The only thing matters for blockings is [TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173763.aspx).

I suppose, you should use WAITFOR as an extreme measure, when exact execution time is important. Otherwise, you should review your code pursuing design improvement.